# Excel printing shrink pictures

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file sheet with rows like this:[image]

I'm facing an issue when trying to print. The "Fit All Columns On One Page" option will shrink all the pictures and font size.

- Is there a way to keep the same image size and fit all the columns when priting?
- is it possible to generate a pdf instead and assign new size and font values to the cells (vba)?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freezing the pane did the trick perfectly using Excel Interop.

```
aSheet.Activate();
aSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = 1;
aSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the Object positioning under Format Picture -> Properties?  Selecting "Move but don't size with cells" should retain the size when printing.

Comment: What file type is the picture?  Maybe try converting to a bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

The page scaling needs to be adjusted to 100% for the picture to be printed at its original size. Set the **Width** and **Height** to Automatic.

[image]

Then view the worksheet in **Page Break Preview** view,

[image]

adjust each column width so that all fit into one page. Don't adjust any page break to fit the columns.

Finally to make it into pdf, simply **Save As** a pdf file.

Using VBA is not advisable as it doesn't seems to be a repetitive task unless you are doing this at least on a daily basis.